# Get query param from url problem when getting url param from module

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to learn angular. I have small problem and i dont know how to solve it.
I have this module:

```
  const hostHandler = setContext((operation: any, context: any) => ({
    headers: {
      ...context?.headers,
      'X-Location-Hostname': hostname,
      'X-Location-Origin': origin,
      'X-App-Mode': test,
      'X-Language': get query param here,
    },
  }));
```

I have a problem because i would like to get url param when somebody writes ?country="UK". I all exapples i watched so far i this always something like this:

```
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const firstParam: string = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('country');

  }
}
```

When i try to add class to module it always gives an error where it states that i need decorator. Is there someway i could get query param and send it with headers?

I tried to get query param in app component and save it in storage like this:

```
 public ngOnInit() {
     this.store.dispatch(new GetNavigation());
     this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      if(params["country"])
      {
        localStorage.setItem('countryParam', params["country"]);
      }

    })
  }
```

It works but problem is that part of code in module is executed before that so i get correct value from storage only when i refresh the page because then storage is populated and country can be sent.

Can someone give me some advice?

Comment: Please elaborate, what do you mean with `When i try to add class to module`

Comment: I am completely new so maybe i am trying impossible and stupid things :). I tried to copy that class i mentioned above into the module so i could somehow get that query parameter and try to give thet value to hostHandler, but there was an error that i am missing directive. Don't know if that is even good solution.

Comment: No, modules shouldn't contain stuff like that. The code snippet you want to include is used within components.

Comment: Ok, i understand. But how can i then get query parameters to use within module? How can i fetch country parameter from url inside module? I tried putting it in storage and it works from app.component but my hostHandler from module gets fired before app.component.

Comment: A module shouldn't do any kind of business logic. For the purpose of adding headers to a request please check the concept of `interceptor`

Comment: Thank you for idea. I tried interceptor and i can intercept request and change x-language. But for now i can only change it by setting it manualy like: const authReq = req.clone({

          headers: req.headers.set('X-Language', 'fi')
        });
But if i try to get query params from interceptor then query param is empty even if i have query param in url like ?country=UK . Is it posible to fetch query param from interceptor before headers are sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.queryParams.pipe(
    map(params => params["country"])
  ).subscribe({
    next: (country) => { 
      localStorage.setItem('countryParam', country);
      const hostHandler = setContext((operation: any, context: any) => ({
        headers: {
          ...context?.headers,
          'X-Location-Hostname': hostname,
          'X-Location-Origin': origin,
          'X-App-Mode': test,
          'X-Language': get query param here,
        },
      }));
      this.store.dispatch(new GetNavigation());
    }
  })
}
```

Move the function that calls the setContext inside the callback for the subscribe function.

Comment: Hi owen. Thank you for answering. I tried that solution but i got lots of errors.

Comment: ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts:83:7 - error TS2348: Value of type 'MapConstructor' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?
    
    83       Map(params => params["country"])
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    src/app/app.component.ts:83:11 - error TS7006: Parameter 'params' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Comment: ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts:83:7 - error TS2552: Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?
    
    83       map(params => params["country"])
             ~~~
    
      node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts:36:13
        36 declare var Map: MapConstructor;
                       ~~~
        'Map' is declared here.
    src/app/app.component.ts:83:11 - error TS7006: Parameter 'params' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Comment: 83       map(params => params["country"])
                 ~~~~~~
    src/app/app.component.ts:86:46 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

    86         localStorage.setItem('countryParam', country)

Comment: I have added an example of the approach in stackblitz and it throws no error; NB: **change Map to map**, and `import {map} from 'rxjs/operators'`

Comment: Hey Owen. You were right it was missing import. Now it works, but again headers are sent before local storage is populated and wrong value is sent. When i type ?coutry=UK value UK is not in storage before headers are sent and they have last value, and then if i again type it in url then correct country is sent because brom last time local storage is populated with correct value (UK)

Comment: Hi Owen.Thank you for your effort, i will mark this as answer, but sadly i cant use it because i can't move host handler from module. I have created interceptor and inside:  const authReq = req.clone({

        headers: req.headers.set('X-Language',localStorage.getItem('countryParam')). When i type UK manualy instead of local storage, it work but as soon as i try to get it from storage i always get last value for the first time :)